# Volume of the region limited by $z=1-x^2$, $y+z=1$ and $x,y,z>0$

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I plot the region, but can't add a picture here... From the picture, I would say that the desired volume is
$$ V = \int _{x=0} ^1 \int _{y=0} ^\infty \int _{z=0} ^{1-x^2} 1 \ dzdydx $$
But, of course, this cannot be true. The answer is infinity. Please, any help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Based on this and your other similar question, I think you should make use of a three-dimensional plotting engine and identify the intended region. [Desmos 3D](https://www.desmos.com/3d) is newly-ish available.

Comment: Why infinity for $y$? If $y>1$ then $z<0$, which contradicts $z>0$. The upper limit for $y$ is $1-z$

Comment: Could you please tell me the limits of integration? It would be $x\in [0,1]$, $z\in ?$, $y\in [0,1-z]$? Or it is better to make a different order? Thanks @Andrei

Comment: As posted in your question, $z\in[0,1-x^2]$. $$V=\int_{x=0}^1dx\int_{z=0}^{1-x^2}dz\int_0^{1-z}dy$$